# Question URL slugs based on title

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, slug

We have always made a best effort to identify questions by making the slugs for each question part of the URL.  The pattern we have selected strips all letters that are not [a-z] or [0-9] and replaces spaces with dashes.  We have found this does help for both usability and indexing a question via google.

We are exploring cases where a slug replacement isn't enough, for example:

[Best collection for data in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717604/best-collection-for-data-in-c-net) we transform the slug to:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717604/best-collection-for-data-in-c-net`

Notice in this example that C# has been truncated to just C which isn't really what we'd like to see in the slug.  A better representation might be:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717604/best-collection-for-data-in-c-sharp-net`

This may or may not yield a better search result via google, however it seems like a good experiment to try.  Are there other cases where a transliterated title based on a table of matched words and their slug replacement may help with search or usability?

Comment: Has anyone considered asking Matt Cutts? ... He responded: https://twitter.com/#!/mattcutts/status/123597479743725568

Answer (score 8):

One obvious candidate is **C++**. For example, "[Importing C++ enumerations into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765/importing-c-enumerations-into-c)" currently gets converted into the slug `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765/importing-c-enumerations-into-c`. A better slug would be `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765/importing-cpp-enumerations-into-csharp`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only confuzzling the [Tiobe index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).  It thinks that C is the hottest language, it is just a hair short of beating Java as the most popular language.  Hehe.

Google otherwise has no problem with it.

Comment: Amazing what you can claim once you (deludedly) realize that C, C++ and C# are the same thing!!!